# passing a very large string as byte array from C++ to C# with Dllimport

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have a very large string in **my c++ dll** file , I need to pass it to C# as a byte array and I have no idea how to do that !

I know I can use this function in C# :

> string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytearray);

- My large string is a **std::string** in C++

**I need to know how can I convert my string to A utf8 array and send it to C# and how to get string back in C# application :)**

**More about the question:**

- I don't know how to pars byte arrays from C++ to C# like swprintf to StringBuilder .
- Here's an example code for my question :

**C++ Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall sendasbyte(char* byte_to_send)
{
    std::ifstream file_t("testfile.txt");
    std::string Read_test_file((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    ///// NEED TO SEND Read_test_file as byte array to C# HERE :
    // <-------- CODE AREA --------->
}
```

**Here's C# Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace minimal_project_testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("minimal_project_test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern void sendasbyte(byte[] get_String_Byte);
        private static byte[] data_from_cpp;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sendasbyte(data_from_cpp);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data_from_cpp);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**And the testfile.txt : https://textuploader.com/dvvbb**

Comment: Check that the bytes in C++ correctly encode the text as UTF-8.

Comment: You are sending 8 bit text and interpreting it as UTF16. You aren't going to solve the problem by trial and error. Some understanding is needed. Start with the most simple test program that you can share here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf sorry I don't know how and how I can transform it to C# like string builder :) I edited the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan any mintue now ...

Comment: Your C++ code leaks, and what you have posted is incomplete. The bug is likely in the code that you didn't show. [mcve]. Don't pfaff around with files for this. Simplify. Make it minimal. That's debugging 101.

Comment: I don't get your word , code is complete !** I have no bug I need to know how can I pass my large string to my C# app :D ** but I updated codes.

Comment: Now you've changed your code completely. I give up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan lol , sorry dude ! I got my answer :D can you please remove the question ?

Comment: If you have an answer, at least post it yourself so that future visitors can benefit from it.

Comment: @Rook Good Idea , I post it now , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to Do That **clear and perfectly** :D

1 > Change your **c++ function** to this :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall test_int()
{
    std::ifstream file_t("testfile.txt");
    std::string Read_test_file((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_t)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    int size_of_st = Read_test_file.length(); 
    std::string test1 = std::to_string(size_of_st);
    char* cstr = new char [size_of_st];
    std::strcpy(cstr, Read_test_file.c_str());
    return cstr; 
}
```

2 > **Don't forgot** to add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

3 > Add **Dllimport** to your C# application

```
[DllImport("minimal_project_test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr test_int();
```

4 > And finally use it **everywhere you need** like this :

```
        IntPtr _test_from_Cpp = test_int();
        int _test_char_count = <Enter Length of your string>;
        byte[] _out_char_value = new byte[_test_char_count];
        Marshal.Copy(_test_from_Cpp, _out_char_value, 0, _test_char_count);
        string final_string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_out_char_value);
```

Boom! it Works !!! ;)

Comment: Leaks. Doesn't include null terminator so no way to determine length. Needless copying in the unmanaged code. All in all, not good.